# My C code does not catch "End Customer" to end

Tags: c

I am writing a code in C to read in customer data from the user and prints the customer data on
the screen until the customer name "End Customer" (i.e., first_name last_name) is read.

I thought that including the if loop and strcmp() will catch the input "End Customer" and prevent printing of customer record. However, when I run it, it does not end. Here is my main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct account {
   struct
   {
      char lastName[10];
      char firstName[10];
   } names;
   int accountNum;
   double balance;
};
void nextCustomer(struct account *acct);
void printCustomer(struct account acct);
int main()
{
   struct account record;
   int flag = 0;

   do {
      nextCustomer(&record);
      if ((strcmp(record.names.firstName, "End") == 0) && //I thought this would be able to catch the End Customer//
          (strcmp(record.names.lastName, "Customer") == 0))
         flag = 1;
      if (flag != 1)
         printCustomer(record);
   } while (flag != 1);
}
```

These are my 2 functions for reading in the customer data and printing customer data respectively:

```
void nextCustomer(struct account *acct)
{
    struct account {
       struct
       {
          char lastName[10];
          char firstName[10];
       } names;
       int accountNum;
       double balance;
    } record;
    printf("Enter names (firstName lastName): ");
        
    scanf("%s %s", (acct->names).firstName, (acct->names).lastName);
    printf("Enter account number: ");
    scanf("\n");
    scanf("%d", &acct->accountNum);
    printf("Enter balance: ");
    scanf("%lf", &acct->balance);
}
```

```
void  printCustomer(struct account acct)
{
    printf("Customer record: \n %s %s %d %.2lf\n", acct.names.firstName, acct.names.lastName, acct.accountNum, acct.balance);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you get any warnings, as `#include <stdio.h>` is not included. Compile the program with `-Wall` flag to see the compile time warnings.

Comment: The code is working as is... Do you want it to quit as soon as you enter the first and last name? If so you'll have to change the code to accommodate that.

Comment: @shubham i included include <stdio.h> in alr! but the next line "Enter account number: " appears even after I type "End Customer" as input into "Enter names: ".

Comment: @Tur1ng Yes! it is working but the code does not quit after I input "End Customer'. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought i accommodated it into my main function already using the if loop and strcmp() for End Customer?

Comment: Move the `strcmp` check in `nextCustomer` itself and return before `Enter account number`

Answer (score 0):

Your current code will execute `nextCustomer` fully until it is done scanning all inputs (name, account number, and balance). Only after that does the code check the first and last names. You need to check the names *right* after you scan them, so you can quit early if you get "End Customer".

Check this code out for a solution: https://onlinegdb.com/HJr_YS9Yw

Answer (score 0):

To implement as you want(not showing account number after 'End Customer'), you have to compare string in nextCustomer definition.

Giving return value is such a good approach.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct account {
    struct {
        char lastName[10];
        char firstName[10];
    } names;
    int accountNum;
    double balance;
};
int nextCustomer(struct account *acct);
void printCustomer(struct account acct);
int main() {
    struct account record;
    int flag = 0;
    do {
        flag = nextCustomer(&record);
        if (flag != 1)
            printCustomer(record);
    } while (flag != 1);
}

int nextCustomer(struct account *acct) {
    struct account {
        struct {
            char lastName[10];
            char firstName[10];
        } names;
        int accountNum;
        double balance;
    } record;
    printf("Enter names (firstName lastName): ");

    scanf("%s %s", (acct->names).firstName, (acct->names).lastName);
    if ((strcmp((acct->names).firstName, "End") ==
         0) &&
        (strcmp((acct->names).lastName, "Customer") == 0))
        return 1; // Returns end code
    printf("Enter account number: ");
    scanf("\n");
    scanf("%d", &acct->accountNum);
    printf("Enter balance: ");
    scanf("%lf", &acct->balance);
    return 0;
}

void printCustomer(struct account acct) {
    printf("Customer record: \n %s %s %d %.2lf\n", acct.names.firstName,
           acct.names.lastName, acct.accountNum, acct.balance);
}
```